# What can be a specific word?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idioms

What can be a specific word that describes something or a particular situation which has been achieved from a person's own hard work?

Comment: Could you use it in a sentence with _____ representing the word?  That would help clarify what you're looking for.  Also, please provide a few examples of what you tried searching for in thesaurus and why that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think "achievement" might be a suitable word, referring to  the results  you have obtained after having worked hard.